Crazy acceleration with EVAL-ADXL373Z
I am extremely new to both Raspberry Pi and working with MicroPython (and i2c protocol). When trying to read data from the EVAL-ADXL373 using Raspberry Pi Pico W I get values ranging from 0 m/s^2 to 128461.60 m/s^2 while it is lying still on the table...
Could someone please give me any tips on where it might be going wrong?
import machine
import time

# Register addresses
ADDRESS_ADXL373 = 0x53
ADDRESS_POWER_CTL = 0x3F
ADDRESS_MEASURE = 0x3E
ADDRESS_TIMING = 0x3D
ADDRESS_XDATA_H = 0x08
ADDRESS_XDATA_L = 0x09
ADDRESS_YDATA_H = 0x0A
ADDRESS_YDATA_L = 0x0B
ADDRESS_ZDATA_H = 0x0C
ADDRESS_ZDATA_L = 0x0D

# Constants
SCALE_FACTOR = 0.2  # 200 mg per LSB scaling factor
GRAVITY_EARTH = 9.815220  # gravity of earth in m/s^2 #uppmätt i Smygehuk

# Initialize I2C #vad betyder freq här ? men detta är rätt
# Vilken freq ska vi använda?
i2c = machine.I2C(0, scl=machine.Pin(5), sda=machine.Pin(4), freq=400000)  # Specify GPIO pins for SCL and SDA

def setup():
    # Initialize serial communication
    uart = machine.UART(0, 115200)  # UART0 with baud rate 115200
    uart.init(115200, bits=12, parity=None, stop=1)

    # Configure ADXL373 sensor #osäker på vad som händer här, vad menas?
    i2c.writeto_mem(ADDRESS_ADXL373, ADDRESS_POWER_CTL, bytearray([0x03]))  # Activate full bandwidth measurement mode
    time.sleep(0.05)
    i2c.writeto_mem(ADDRESS_ADXL373, ADDRESS_MEASURE, bytearray([0x04]))  # Set output signal bandwidth to 2560 Hz #0x04=00000100
    time.sleep(0.05)
    i2c.writeto_mem(ADDRESS_ADXL373, ADDRESS_TIMING, bytearray([0x80]))  # Set output data rate to 5120 Hz
    time.sleep(0.05)

def loop_X():
    while True:
        # Read X-axis acceleration data
        i2c.writeto_mem(ADDRESS_ADXL373, ADDRESS_XDATA_H, bytearray([0x0]))
        x_data = i2c.readfrom_mem(ADDRESS_ADXL373, ADDRESS_XDATA_H, 2)
        xAxisH = x_data[0]
        xAxisL = x_data[1]

        # Combine high and low bytes
        xAxisFinal = (xAxisH << 8 | xAxisL) #& 0xFFF0  # Apply bitmask to maintain 12-bit resolution

        # Convert raw data to acceleration
        xAccel = xAxisFinal * SCALE_FACTOR * GRAVITY_EARTH

        # Print acceleration
        print("Xa = {:.2f}".format(xAccel))
        #print("XH={:.2f}".format(xAxisH))
        #print("XL={:.2f}".format(xAxisL))

        # Delay before next reading
        time.sleep(0.2)
        

# Run setup function
setup()

# Run main loop for X
loop_X()

´´´


Could you pls explain what it is you're trying to measure? Is it the m/s^2? What is that exactly? And I guess this EVAL-ADXL373 has a data sheet? Where is it? Can we get a copy? How many marshmallows can a Martian eat in 14.6 parsecs?? (Hope I've made my point)

You might include that the EVAL-ADXL373 is an analog.com evaluation board for the "ADXL373 Micropower, 3-Axis, ±400 g, Digital Output, MEMS Accelerometer". I'll ask also, did you read the specifications? You are only looking at X (of sensors X, Y & Z) in your code. How do you know that is the one pointing toward the earth (that is, if you were expecting 9.8m/s^2 reading)?

If you're getting unexpected values, calibration might be necessary. You might need to calibrate the accelerometer to account for any offset or bias in the readings. Print out the raw data (xAxisH, xAxisL) before converting it to acceleration values. This will help you verify if you're reading the data correctly from the accelerometer. If you ever consider using something similar, you can use MPU6050. https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2019/02/introduction-to-mpu6050.html

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Check that your I2C communication is working properly. There should be no wiring issues, and the correct I2C address is being used to communicate with the sensor. Also check the scale factor you're using for converting the raw sensor data to acceleration values. You can also cross-check your accelerometer with an Arduino. You can also switch to a low cost solution like LIS3DSH sensor if needed: https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/LIS3DSH_evaluation_board.html

It is likely you are interpreting the output of the analog.com X accelerometer sensor as an unsigned integer when they are actually 2s complement values. Let us revers your calculations and use a 2s complement interpretation of the value read from the accelerometer:
Consider the provided value 128461:
((128461 / 9.815220) / 0.2) = 65439
Which is -96.
Therefore, the two readings (if we assume you have set up the accelerometer correctly and your assumption the accelerometer granularity of 200mG is correct) are 0 and -188.4.
While much more reasonable, the values are still far enough off to question their usefulness.
Consider checking the specifications to make sure the accelerometer configurations are correct and the granularity is actually 200mG.
Also, consider the accelerometer needs to be calibrated before use. In many cases the offset and magnitude errors only need to be found once for each accelerometer then re-used from that point on.
